# How to send different message to different numbers by default SMS app Android programmatically?

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions, smsmanager

I made a school-related app. I have a feature where I need to send a "Customized message" for all students/parents based on their own data *(Suppose , their attendance data after their attendance has been taken by teachers then every parents will get an SMS from my app)* .

But the Google play store is rejecting this update continuously. They consider the `SEND_SMS` permission as sensitive permission but for this specific use case, I need to do that. It is not possible to send a customized message to every single student with their numbers easily with the default SMS app.

Here is [an email reply](https://pastebin.pl/view/f562d3f9) from the google support team.
And here is the [Google permission policy](https://support.google.com/.../android.../answer/10208820...).

What might be a proper solution without rewriting the business logic? I'm thinking of making the app a default app sender but it needs rewriting business logic and also a hesitation about a policy violation. I can't send SMS by API getaway as my users are not capable to pay for it. And I'm not finding any useful solution to send single student-based SMS via my default SMS app with a single click.